# jenkins ignores "inclusive regions"

Tags: git, jenkins

I have two jenkins projects

1) one that polls over git repo

2) second that triggers java application

I want to configure (1) to poll on a specific file only, so i did it under "inclusive regions". However, i see the project is triggered after every change in the repo, not only when the specific file is changed.

Has anyone experienced the same?

Other work around?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Following the question "[Jenkins Git plugin included regions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19638335/6309)", make sure that:

- your "included region" is a path relative to the root folder of your Git repo.

  ```
  a/b/c...bal/sdk.conf
  ```
- "Force polling using workspace" under "Source-Code-Management - Additional Behaviours"

Note: there are still open bugs relative to "included regions":

- "[JENKINS-28032: Included Regions do not work when monitoring all branches](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28032)"

Make sure you are not monitoring all branches.